# Want to save a <td> tag content on a cookie by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, onclick

I am trying to make a function which will save a TD tag content by clicking on it, such as :

```
<td>Test</td>
```

In this case, for exemple, "Test" value would be saved on a cookie.
I am relatively new from PHP, and i know it is not a big deal but i do not know how to handle it.
PS : There is no things such as ID, Class etc... on any of my TD, but if it is necessary, i can add them.
my TD looks like this :

```
<td style='cursor: pointer'>" . $row['number']."</td>
```

Thanks you for everything

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery library for cookie. See the plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

Then you can use the below code where you set id for the td

```
$("#td").on("click", function(){

  var name = $("#td").val();

  $.cookie('name',name);

}
```